# How to integrate an address with Google Map dynamically ?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using PHP Laravel 4.0 on my application.

Here is an example of one of my user address :

[image: img]

At the end, in `Location` section, I place all of them next to each other as an address format.

In addition, I want to use that address and integrate it with Google Maps.

### What I've tried ?

The address is `410 Walker Street Lowell MA 01851`

I use this site.
http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocode

to grab its location, I got this

`42.635507, -71.328928`

Then I include them in my HTML like this 
I got them from https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.635507, -71.328928),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Questions

Since I've a lot of users on my application. It will be a hard for me to do it manually - one by one. 
I want to make it `dynamically generate` to all the addresses on all the pages in my application.

- Base on what I've tried, can someone help me or give me a little hint on this?
- Can you tell me what I missed ?
- What is the logics behind this ?
- Do I need to download a specific packages or plug-in for that ?

HUGE `thanks` to everyone that involve on this post !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Maps Geocode Service to decode your address:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?hl=pt-br

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function codeAddress(address) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latlng = results[0].geometry.location; // this is what you want
      alert(latlng)
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

With a LatLng value you may use it to center the map

```
map.setCenter(latlng);
```

Or even draw a marker

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latlng
  });
```

But looking deep into your sample. You may only need to insert a embed iframe pointing right to the address you get from PHP. First you need to generate an [API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#api_key) and then use it as the sample below:

```
<iframe
    width="600"
    height="450"
    frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
      &q=<? echo "YOUR ADDRESS FROM PHP"?>
      &attribution_source=Google+Maps+Embed+API">
 </iframe>
```

Comment: I did this `<iframe
    width="600"
    height="450"
    frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=My_KEY
      &q=<?php echo $latlng; ?>
      &attribution_source=Google+Maps+Embed+API">
 </iframe>` - I got an error said, undefined $latlng. So far, I like your answer, I will make sure to accept it as soon as I get this running.

Comment: latlng was defined in Javascript (client), not in PHP. Instead of $latlng you should point to a variable defined in PHP (server) containing the addres "410 Walker Street Lowell MA 01851"

Answer (score 0):

urlencodeUse PHP to get the geo code data.  This will also verify the address is correctly formatted and will give the properly formatted address when needed.  And I included a custom address format for display purposes.  If the address cannot be geo coded then it popes up the address to be re-submitted.

You may have missed putting a marker at the location.

```
    $address = urlencode'410 Walker Street Lowell MA 01851');

    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($formatted_address) . '&sensor=false';
    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($data,true);
    $tLat = $data['results']['0']['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $tLng = $data['results']['0']['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    $formatted_address = $data['results']['0']['formatted_address'];
    $address_components = array();
    $address_components = $data['results']['0']['address_components'];
    foreach ($address_components as $key => $val){
      if ($val['types'][0] == 'route'){
        $route = addslashes($val['short_name']);
      }
      elseif ($val['types'][0] == 'locality'){
        $locality = addslashes($val['short_name']);
      }
      elseif ($val['types'][0] == 'postal_code'){
        $postal_code = $val['long_name'];
      }
      elseif ($val['types'][0] == 'street_number'){
        $street_number = addslashes($val['long_name']);
      }
    }


    if (strlen($street_number) > 0){ 
      echo "$addr$customer<div id=\"map\"></div>";
      <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
      <script>
      var map;
      function initialize() {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var cntr = new google.maps.LatLng($tLat, $tLng);
      var mapOptions = {zoom:15,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,center: cntr}
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: cntr,map: map,title:"xxxxxxxxx"});

      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      }
    else{
      echo "<p id=\"addr\">$formatted_address <form action=\"addressCheck.php\"  method=\"post\" ><button id=\"sub\" value=\" Edit and Re-Submit \"> Edit and Re-Submit </button><input class=\"txt\" type=\"text\" name=\"addr\" value=\"$address\" /></form>";  
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to get location after user enter her location ?
try this code snippet, may be a little help for you

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-2.548926, 118.0148634),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);

    var input = document.getElementById("keyword");
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", map);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        zoom:14,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(15);
        }

        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
        marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:530px; height:250px"></div>
<label for="keyword">Location :</label>
<input type="text" class="span6" name="keyword" id="keyword">
```